# Why this java link checker code does not compile?

Tags: java, hyperlink, broken-links

I already read the [link checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65515/how-to-find-broken-links-on-a-website) question posted in SO. If there are more questions of this kind and I missed them, my apologies.

We need to find broken links in a [website](http://blog.readytocloud.com) in a very easy way and scriptable way, so we can document the links that are broken.  I found a [blog post](http://unserializableone.blogspot.com/2008/12/link-checker-with-java-better-version.html) with some code written in java that will do exactly what I need, and my very basic knowledge let me compile it, but I get errors every time. I thought that maybe someone here might be able to direct me to why the code does not compile.

Here is the code:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
class links
{

private static boolean isLive(String link) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
      URL url = new URL(link);
      urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      urlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
      urlConnection.connect();
      String redirectLink = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
      if (redirectLink != null && !url.equals(redirectLink)) {
        return isLive(redirectLink);
      } else {
        return urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
    } finally {
      if (urlConnection != null) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isLive("http://www.fakelink.net"));
  }
}
```

Thanks to all that reply.  I putting the code that compiles here, for future reference.

Comment: Voted up for updating code with correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the proper packages imported. In this case, you should have the follow at the top of the file:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
```

I'm also getting a compiler warning on the following piece of code:

```
 && !url.equals(redirectLink)
```

It's trying to equate url (which is a URL) to redirectLink (which is a String). In Java it will automatically compare the string value when this happens and the toString actually gives what you want. To be more precise in the authors code I would change the above code to:

```
 && !url.toExternalForm().equals(redirectLink)
```

Note: In netbeans, you can simply right click and select the option Fix Imports (or hit Ctrl + Shift + I) and it will try to find the correct packages that you're currently using and automatically insert the import statements.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems correct. May be you have not imported the required Packages. It will help if you could post the compiler errors that you are getting.

Comment: thanks very much.  I will do that early in the morning.  Thanks.