# What to use to check html links in large project, on Linux?

Tags: html, linux, hyperlink

I have directory with > 1000 .html files, and would like to check all of them for bad links - preferably using console. Any tool you can recommend for such task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract links from html files using [Lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/) text browser. Bash scripting around this should not be difficult.

Comment: Lynx can do it, but it doesn't really support it.  wget is much better suited for the purpose.

Comment: How do you get wget to output a list of links in a page?

Answer (score 4):

you can use `wget`, eg

```
wget -r --spider  -o output.log http://somedomain.com
```

at the bottom of the output.log file, it will indicate whether `wget` has found broken links. you can parse that using `awk/grep`

Comment: An alternative **wget** command line to check for broken links can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15029100/1497596). Also note that a comment that I left on that answer provides a link to **wget for Windows**.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [checklink](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?checklink) (a W3C project)

Comment: As long as you are careful to set the user agent and accept headers (to avoid bogus error codes from bot detectors) this should work.

Comment: It would look ok, but it's definitely not intended for such large projects - it doesn't have any way to just list broken links, and output for my project is *really* big.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [webgrep](http://www.linuxfocus.org/~guido.socher/#webgrep) command line tools or, if you're comfortable with Perl, the [HTML::TagReader](http://www.linuxfocus.org/~guido.socher/#TagReader) module by the same author.